# trigger create and test harness errors

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER policy_check_system_test
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF policy_type_code ON policy
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
  is_furnished CHAR(1);
  last_policy_enddate DATE;
BEGIN 
  -- Check if the policy type is Contents and the property is fully furnished
  IF UPPER(:NEW.policy_type_code) = UPPER('C') THEN 
    SELECT prop_fully_furnished 
    INTO is_furnished
    FROM property 
    WHERE prop_no = :NEW.prop_no;
    
    IF is_furnished <> 'Y' THEN 
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Cannot add Contents policy if property is not fully furnished.');
    else 
      dbms_output.put_line('Added Contents policy successfully');
    END IF;
-- Check for previous policy end date for non-Contents policy types
    SELECT MAX(policy_enddate)
    INTO last_policy_enddate
    FROM policy
    WHERE prop_no = :NEW.prop_no
    AND policy_type_code = :NEW.policy_type_code 
    AND policy_enddate IS NOT NULL;
    
    IF :NEW.policy_startdate <= last_policy_enddate THEN 
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'Start date must be after the end date of the previous policy of the same type.');
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSfaQ.png)

I tried to test the trigger but failed many times and it shows

```
Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'INSERT_CHECK' is invalid and failed re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.
```

does someone know how to solve it ?
the task is to create one trigger that could check the Contents (‘C’) policy can only be added to the database when  the property is fully furnished
and the new policy start date for the property and policy type must be after the previous policy’s end date of the same policy type.

Comment: What is the actual error? It should show up when you run `select * from user_errors;`

Comment: Observation: It is redundant and unnecessary to use `UPPER('C')`, just use `UPPER(:NEW.policy_type_code) = 'C'`. Also, your select from `policy` in the second `if` condition will result in a mutating table error at runtime. You can't select from the table being modified from within a row-level trigger. These kinds of conditions are generally checked in client code or in server-side API code *before* the insert or update is executed. Neither of those things would keep the trigger from being compiled, however.